# How can I provide suggestions for parameter without enforcing validation in bicep?

Tags: azure-bicep

I'm developing bicep templates for our developers and wan't to provide suggestion for SKU's.

I'm using a user defined type for this but when doing that the user is enforced to choose one of the values that I declared, I want them able to choose what they want but get the suggestions from my type.

This is what I have:

```
type Sku = 'P0v3' | 'P1v3'
```

But I want something like this :

```
type Sku = 'P0v3' | 'P1v3' | *wildcard*
```

Is there any way or workaround to achieve that in bicep? Thanks!

Comment: Seems like it's not possible but there is an open github issue related to this: https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/10432

Comment: As a workaround, you can define `type Sku = String`. So that Developers can provider their own values as detailed in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/user-defined-data-types#user-defined-data-type-syntax). @mrplatina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-any#any) function in bicep as a workaround. In your scenario, it can be used to modify user input to `Sku` type. Sample way is shown below.

```
type Sku = 'P0v3' | 'P1v3' 
param skuInput string  
var skunew = any(skuInput)
```

*I tried deploying a sample storage account by applying the above function and was deployed successfully as shown.*

[image]

[image]

As an alternative workaround, you can define `type Sku = String`. Later developers can provide their own values accordingly as detailed in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/user-defined-data-types#user-defined-data-type-syntax).

Comment: Thanks but with this solution they won't get my recommendations? I would like to provide P0V3 and P1V3 as recommended options.

Comment: I'm looking for something like this 

type Sku = 'P0V3' | 'P1V3' | *:string

Comment: That is not possible with Bicep as per my workaround. @mrplatina

Comment: Thanks, so i guess the workaround for devs is to use any in their param file (if they use bicepparam) ? In your example above i guess the skuinput should be of type sku

Comment: Yes correct. @mrplatina